# Wallet Balance Incorrectly Displays 0, missing Transaction Keys?

Tags: wallet

My wallet is unusable at the moment, and sending xmr results in an doublespend error.

**Transaction Amount for Sent tx** "unknown amount" as the amount of xmr sent.  This "unknown amount" was sent to My Wallet.  ( This is displayed for the *penultimate* transaction, though as far as I can tell, all outgoing and incoming transactions look to be genuine, intentional spends.  )

**Transaction Key**: " - " (Upon further inspection, I noticed that not a single transaction in my wallet will display anything other than " - " as its transaction key.)

**What I've done**: Restored the wallet from seed.  No effect.

Without any guidance, I'm going to redownload the entire chain and then once again restore from seed, with fingers crossed.  Is there something else that I should be doing?

*OS: Macos 11.2.3
GUI Version: 0.17.1.9-3ca5f10 (Qt 5.12.8)*

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the chain is pointless.
Restoring the wallet from seed will wipe the transaction keys.
A double spend like this after a restore from seed/keys can be caused by an outgoing transaction being stuck in the daemon, waiting to be spent. The outputs spent in that tx are not spent on chain, but the daemon will still reject reuse of them since it's already got a tx waiting to be mined. You can fix this by running "rescan_spent" in monero-wallet-cli. I believe there's a button for this in the options somewhere in the GUI,
I don't know about the "unknown amount" thing, that seems odd, but it seems GUI specific. See what monero-wallet-cli reports.